# want to access the value of a cell of a select query

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In my application I'm storing the the color in my table `emp` like this :

```
+---------+------------------+
| emp     |  id      | color |
+---------+------------------+
| hary    | 123      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| lary    | 125      | green |
+---------+------------------+
| gary    | 038      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| Kris    | 912      | blue  |
+---------+------------------+
| hary    | 123      |  red  |
+---------+------------------+
| Ronn    | 334      | green |
+---------+------------------+
```

Now for counting how many times the color code appear I have written this :

```
select color,count(*) Count
from emp where (color like '%bl%' or color like '%ree%')
group by color
```

so I get the result like

```
+---------------
| color |Count |
+---------------
|   red |   3  | 
+---------------
|  blue |   1  | 
+---------------
| green |   2  | 
+---------------
```

now I want to access each color-code's count i.e. cell value,so how do I have to approach it in terms of java(jdbc).I've written this in a jsp page:

```
<html
<body>
<div>
<table>
<% while(rs.next()){ %>

    <tr>
      <th>HDYK Stat</th><th>NUMBER</th>
     </tr>

    <tr style="color: #0DA068">
      <td><%=rs.getString("color") %></td><td><%= rs.getInt("Count")%></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="color: #194E9C">
      <td><%=rs.getString("color") %></td><td><%= rs.getInt("Count")%></td>
    </tr>
   <tr style="color: #ED9C13">
   <td><%=rs.getString("color") %></td><td><%= rs.getInt("Count")%></td>
   </tr>

<%      
} 
%>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it's repeating 3 times: like red : 3,blue : 3,green : 1,red : 1,blue : 1,green : 1,red :2...
Any inputs on this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the result set and pull each columns value.

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select color,count(*) Count from emp where (color like '%bl%' or color like'%ree%') group by color";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String color = rs.getString("color");
            int count = rs.getInt("Count");
            System.out.println("Color: " + color + " Count: " + count);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        //Something
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

Although, I wouldn't recommend accessing your result set via the JSP, it can be done as follows:

**First iterate through all of the rows and set their `class` attribute.**

```
<% while(rs.next()){ %>

    <tr>
      <th>HDYK Stat</th><th>NUMBER</th>
     </tr>

    <tr class="<%=rs.getString("color") %>">
      <td><%=rs.getString("color") %></td><td><%= rs.getInt("Count")%></td>
    </tr>
<%      
} 
%>
```

**Define a style for each color in your CSS**

```
.red{
  color: #0DA068;
}

.blue{
  color:#194E9C;
}

.green{
  color: #ED9C13;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I want the each color's count ,like red : 3,blue : 1,green : 2,it's showing 3 for all color code.

Comment: did you change the query at all?  Are you sure the group by clause is still there? I'm not seeing anything in the code that would cause that, not saying there isn't,but I don't see it.

Comment: I have edited my answer,but still it's print the proper way and once.

Comment: HOw can I access a particual cell value,...could you tell me.

Comment: Gotcha I didn't understand without the html

Comment: b(riallant + eautiful) answer + 1more thing is that actually in terms of output is 2.3.8 as rs.getString("color"), so whenever I 'm going to css it became `.2.3.8` sothe color turns black, how to avoid this thing?

Answer (score 1):

Actually just like you would for `emp`, `id` or `color` - you just look up the column by the name `Count`. That is, your `ResultSet` will have the size 3, and each row will have two columns: `color` and `Count`.

I assume you already know how to talk JDBC in Java?

Cheers,